# Hoc as a word to sum up a previous paragraph

Tags: grammar-choice

I have seen hoc not agreeing with grammatical gender when it refers to a previous paragraph of actions. But I don't remember in what context.

Here is a made up example in English:

I once went to Jamaica. There, I swashbuckled with pirates, gambled with loansharks, and drank mead sailing on the high sea. **This** made me thirsty for another adventure.

Would the **hoc** corresponding to **this** be masculine, feminine, or neuter when describing all of these past deeds at once? Could I say "Hoc est causa" if I wanted to?

Comment: If you want to start the last sentence with 'This is the reason (why I was made thirsty...)' instead of 'This (made me thirsty...)', you would actually, as a matter of good prose style, say, "Haec est causa," where the form of hic/haec/hoc is attracted to the form of causa. So that's something slightly different.

Comment: @cnread And that was actually the original case. I pointed out in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm) *hoc est causa...* should rather have *haec* although it doesn't refer to anything feminine. But of course that phenomenon requires there to be something to attract the form (*hic est **sermo** meus, haec sunt **divitiae** meae*).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Right, and one would say: *Hoc fecit, ut …* (In reality I would not write that at all, but rather: *Qua de causa, qua re, quam ob rem*, or without relative prounouns: *Ob eam rem* etc. But that was not the question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to *[Allen and Greenough, New Latin Grammar](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/allen-greenough/Chapters/Chapter-297.html)*, *hoc* and other demonstrative pronouns are often used in the neuter to refer to entire phrases. Therefore, it's not necessary for them to agree in gender:

> **e.** The pronouns *hīc* , *ille* , and *is* are used to point in either
>   direction, back to something just mentioned or forward to something
>   about to be mentioned.
>
> **f.** The neuter forms often refer to a clause, phrase, or idea:—
>
> *est illud quidem vel maximum, animum vidēre* (Tusc. 1.52), that is in
>   truth a very great thing,— to see the soul.

According to *[Bennett's New Latin Grammar](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bennett.html#sect87)*, the demonstrative pronoun often agrees with the predicate, but he doesn't say that that necessarily has to be the case:

> The above pronouns, along with is, are usually attracted to the gender
>   of a predicate noun; as, **hīc est honor, meminisse officium suum**, 
>   *this is an honor, to be mindful of one's duty*.

Therefore, according to Bennett, you would *usually* want the pronoun to agree: *haec est causa*, as cnread pointed out.